# Google indexes "Hot Network Questions"?

Tags: bug, google, hot-questions

This Google search:

https://www.google.com/search?q=pivotitem+%22position%22+not+correct+site%3Astackoverflow.com

is giving me hits based on content from "Hot network questions" (not very useful in this context) - anyone else see this?

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: Might be a case to add `data-nosnippet` as described here: [Add the data-nosnippet attribute to answers with negative score (-3 or less)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385770)

Comment: Seems more like an indexing issue with Google?  They should not be including "Hot network questions" as indexed content when indexing individual questions...

Comment: The whole point of the "Hot Networking Questions" list is to cause networking effects (i.e. causing posts to go viral).  It would make no sense to screen it out of Google searches; that would defeat its purpose.  Whether that's actually a desirable outcome is another matter.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  - "Whether that's actually a desirable outcome is another matter" well that's my question I suppose?  Is it on balance desirable to make the indexing of SO questions less useful just to promote HNQ which are transient in nature?

Comment: "*They should not be including "Hot network questions"*" how is Google to know what to index and what not to index? Do remember they crawl *all* websites. I doubt Google goes as far as having a separate indexing scheme for each and every website out there.

Comment: @VLAZ - I guess using something like https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots-meta-tag#data-nosnippet-attr  ?   EDIT maybe not: seems like data-nosnippet is just for snippets, not for indexing.  Huh I had thought indexing was more nuanced than it apparently is...

Comment: Yes, HNQ is indexed by Google. Tangential to the issue, long ago before [HNQ entry is added to the timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324641/241919), this is the only unreliable way to check whether a question has entered HNQ or not.